# Python. Проблема с двумерным списком

Tags: python, python-3.x

Имеется задачка:
Выведите таблицу размером n×n, заполненную числами от 1 до n^2 по спирали, выходящей из левого верхнего угла и закрученной по часовой стрелке

```py
a = int(input()) # 5

rez = [[0] * a] * a

pointer = 0
ln = a
b_len = a
edge = 1
x = -1
y = 0

for i in range(a ** 2):

  if pointer == 4:
    pointer = 0
  if pointer == 0:
    x += 1
  if pointer == 1:
    y += 1
  if pointer == 2:
    x -= 1
  if pointer == 3:
    y -= 1

  rez[x][y] = i + 1
  print("rez[" + str(x) + "][" + str(y) + "] = " + str(rez[x][y])) 
  #прим. rez[0][0] = 1
  ln -= 1
  if ln == 0:
    edge -= 1
    pointer += 1
    ln = b_len
  if edge == 0:
    edge = 2
    b_len -= 1
    ln = b_len

x = 0
y = 0
print("\n\nrez[" + str(x) + "][" + str(y) + "] = " + str(rez[x][y]) + "\n\n") 
#rez[0][0] = 5

for i in rez:
  print(*i)
```

В алгоритме я как раз хожу по спирали и заполняю двумерный список. но в результате почему-то, весь список заполняется обратной диагональю от нужного, да при встроенной проверке, ясно, что заполнение происходит правильно но потом *что-то происходит*. Хоть вроде не дурак, но понять проблему никак не могу

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В этой строке Вы создали список из `a` нулей и потом список из `a` его копий (одного и того же списка) положили в `rez`:

```
rez = [[0] * a] * a
```

Это легко проверить, например:

```
 rez[0] is rez[1]    # True
```

Видно, что элементы `rez` - ссылки на одно и то же значение. Соответственно, когда Вы менете `res[0][0]`, меняется и `rez[1][0]`, и `rez[2][0]` и т.д. вплоть до `rez[a-1][0]`. Поэтому делайте начальный список иначе, например:

```
rez = [[0 for idx_y in range(a)] for idx_x in range(a)]
```

Это не приведёт к получению списка из ссылок на одно значение и элементы списка будут меняться по-отдельности.

Comment: Ещё, кстати, при выводе списка как `for i in rez: ¶ print(*i)` получается эффект того, что индексы по x и y перепутаны местами